# Uploading image to repo using VS Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, jekyll

I was beating my head against a wall trying to figure out why I couldn't get an image to display in my Jekyll page. I figured out there were some encoded characters that I couldn't see in the filename.

It looks like VS Code inserted encoding when I edited the markdown file for my post. It added a [U+200E]before the filename in the path. Here's what I see in the VS Code editor when I open the .md file I'm editing

```
![PEGA - 4 timeframes]({{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/images/‎[U+200E]PEGA4tf.png)
```

Any ideas why VS Code insists on inserting an encoding  character? I don't see the character when I edit the file from the GitHub page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just answered my own question. The original image filename had white spaces in it, and VS Code apparently doesn't respond well to any whitespace in the filename. That's an easy problem to fix.